# my GetHttp works with HTTP but HTTPS returns invalid data

Tags: delphi

my GetHttp  works with HTTP but HTTPS returns invalid data, this is the test procedure:

GetHTTP('https://localhost/','',temp,true);
  temp.SaveToFile('c:\temp.txt');

How to fix, any ideas?

```
function GetHTTP(AUrl, APostStr:ansistring; AStream:TStream; noncached :boolean =false): integer;
var
  Retry: Boolean;
  hSession, hConnect, hRequest: hInternet;
  RequestMethod, Header: ansistring;
  Buf:array[0..1023] of Char;
  ReadCount:Cardinal;
  dwError, dwErrorCode: DWORD;
  ptNil: Pointer;

  UrlInfo: TUrlInfo;
  flags : DWORD ;

  procedure SetTimeOut;
  var
    TimeOut: integer;
  begin
    TimeOut := 5 * 1000;
    InternetSetOption(hSession, INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT, @TimeOut,
      SizeOf(TimeOut));
  end;

  procedure GetHttpStatus; //StatusCode   
  var
    Len, Reserved: DWORD;
  begin
    Reserved := 0;
    Len := SizeOf(Result);
    HttpQueryInfo(hRequest, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE or HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER,
      @Result, Len, Reserved) ;
  end;

 begin



   flags := 0;
  if noncached = true then flags := INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD;

//  flags := INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE;    THIS   DID NOT HELP ??!!! output was blank with it

  Result := 0;
  if not GetUrlInfo(AUrl, UrlInfo) then Exit;
  hSession := InternetOpen(nil, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
  try
    SetTimeOut;
    hConnect := InternetConnect(hSession, pchar(UrlInfo.hostname),urlinfo.port,nil,nil,INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP,INTERNET_FLAG_EXISTING_CONNECT ,0);

    try
      if APostStr = '' then
        RequestMethod := 'GET'
      else
        RequestMethod := 'POST';

      hRequest := HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, PChar(RequestMethod),Pchar(urlinfo.urlpath), 'HTTP/1.0', nil, nil,flags, 0);

      try
        if APostStr = '' then
          Header := ''
        else
          Header := 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';


 Retry:=True;
        while Retry do
        begin
          if HttpSendRequest(hRequest, PChar(Header),Length(Header), PChar(APostStr), Length(APostStr)) then
            dwErrorCode:=ERROR_SUCCESS
          else
            dwErrorCode:=GetLastError;
          dwError:=InternetErrorDlg(application.Handle, hRequest, dwErrorCode,
            FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FILTER_FOR_ERRORS or
            FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FLAGS_CHANGE_OPTIONS or
            FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FLAGS_GENERATE_DATA,
            ptNil);
          Retry:=(dwError=ERROR_INTERNET_FORCE_RETRY);
        end;

        //HttpSendRequest(hRequest, PChar(Header),Length(Header), PChar(APostStr), Length(APostStr));



        GetHttpStatus;
        if Result <> HTTP_STATUS_OK then Exit;
        while True do
        begin
          if not InternetReadFile(hRequest, @Buf, SizeOf(Buf), ReadCount) then
            Break;
            //res := GetLastError();
          if ReadCount = 0 then
            Break
          else
            AStream.Write(Buf, ReadCount);
        end;
      finally
        InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);
      end;
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
    end;
  finally
    InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: isn't local certificate required for HTTPS?

Answer (score 2):

I have only done this in Indy, which uses [OpenSSL](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/) and requires a couple of extra DLLs.  You also need to explicitly create an IO handler for SSL.  Here is a simplified code example.

```
MyHTTP := GetIdHTTP(True);
MyHTTP.Get(SomeSecureURL, MyStream);
```

...

```
function GetIdHTTP(aSecure: Boolean = False): TIdHTTP;
var
  lSSLIOHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  Result := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);

  if aSecure then
  begin
    lSSLIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create;
    Result.IOHandler := lSSLIOHandler;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides Indy, you can also use Delphi's THTTPReqResp component (or look at how it handles HTTPS; it uses WinInet). Here's your GetHTTP written using the component for GET:

```
function GetHTTP(AUrl, APostStr: String; AStream:TStream; noncached :boolean =false): Boolean;
var
  ReqResp: THTTPReqResp;
begin
  Result := False;
  ReqResp := THTTPReqResp.Create(nil);
  try
    { Get Case }
    if AUrl <> '' then
    begin
      ReqResp.URL := AUrl;
      ReqResp.Get(AStream);
      Result := True;
    end;
  finally
    ReqResp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: IIRC it has the advantage that no special SSL libraries are needed because it uses the built-in SSL libraries of the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

https runs on a different port, and you need to tell winsock perform a secure connection.

check that `urlinfo.port` is being set to 443 for https requests.
you *have* to set the `INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE` flag for https requests.